# Rotate triangle using rotation matrix - disappears from window

Tags: c++, xcode, rotation, openframeworks

Im trying to rotate a triangle clockwise around its centre, using a rotation matrix. However, the triangle moves off of the screen towards the bottom left.
Here is my code

```
class Triangle {
    public:
    vector<glm::vec3> verts; // positions of the triangles vertices.
    glm::vec3 pos; // position of the triangle's origin.

    void rotate(float rotationMat[4]) {
        // Transform vert 1
        glm::vec3 vert1 = verts[0]; // Get the vertices (centred about the triangle origin)
        vert1 = vert1 - pos; // Get the vertices centered about the origin (0, 0)
        // Rotate the vertices
        vert1.x = (vert1.x * rotationMat[0]) + (vert1.y * rotationMat[1]);
        vert1.y = (vert1.x * rotationMat[2]) + (vert1.x * rotationMat[3]);
        // Get the vertices centered about the triangle origin
        vert1 = vert1 + pos;

        // Set the new vertices value
        verts[0] = vert1;



        // Transform vert2
        glm::vec3 vert2 = verts[1]; // Get the vertices (centered about the triangle origin)
        vert2 = vert2 - pos; // Get the vertices centered about the origin (0, 0)
        // Rotate the vertices
        vert2.x = (vert2.x * rotationMat[0]) + (vert2.y * rotationMat[1]);
        vert2.y = (vert2.x * rotationMat[2]) + (vert2.x * rotationMat[3]);
        // Get the vertices centered about the triangle origin
        vert2 = vert2 + pos;

        // Set the new vertices value
        verts[1] = vert2;



        // Transform vert3
        glm::vec3 vert3 = verts[2]; // Get the vertices (centered about the triangle origin)
        vert3 = vert3 - pos; // Get the vertices centered about the origin (0, 0)
        // Rotate the vertices
        vert3.x = (vert3.x * rotationMat[0]) + (vert3.y * rotationMat[1]);
        vert3.y = (vert3.x * rotationMat[2]) + (vert3.x * rotationMat[3]);
        // Get the vertices centered about the triangle origin
        vert3 = vert3 + pos;

        // Set the new vertices value
        verts[2] = vert3;

    }
};
```

I call the method like so:

```
float rotationMat[4] = { (float) cos(1), (float) -sin(1), (float) sin(1), (float) cos(1)};
triangle.rotate(rotationMat);
```

As a test, I print out the vertices before and after the rotation, here are the results:

```
BEFORE: 
(100,-100)
(0,100)
(-100,-100)

AFTER: 
(788.762,899.003)
(566.437,591.801)
(680.701,749.688)
```

Where am I going wrong here? Why does the triangle fly off of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that:

```
vert1.x = (vert1.x * rotationMat[0]) + (vert1.y * rotationMat[1]);
vert1.y = (vert1.x * rotationMat[2]) + (vert1.x * rotationMat[3]);
```

After the first line, `vert1.x` will have change and the computation you do on the second line won't be valid. Do :

```
auto newx = (vert1.x * rotationMat[0]) + (vert1.y * rotationMat[1]);
auto newy = (vert1.x * rotationMat[2]) + (vert1.x * rotationMat[3]);
vert1.x = newx;
vert1.y = newy;
```

(there might be other issues)

Answer (score 0):

@Jeffrey is right. You need to store the original X for computing the new Y.

In addition, a simple rotational matrix with 4 elements will rotate around the origin, not necessarily the center point.

Thirdly, I warn against using `vector` lists when the number of elements (vertices) is constant (3). Also, seeing as your rotational mask is 2D, you should probably make those vertices 2D as well. This should really be `glm::vec2 verts[3]`, unless you expect "triagnles" to not be triangles or to be in 3D space.

If you want to rotate around the center, use a matrix with a translational component and computed it. 3x3 matrix for 2D, 4x4 for 3D. There are numerous resources for computing the center or using matrix math.